# How to run Flask app by flask run or custom command without set FLASK_APP manually

Tags: python, flask, python-click

### Use case

I have a python package using a `click` group to have multiple command line subcommands.
In addition to this, I would like to have a small flask application.

The other subcommands are the primary function of the package - *not* the flask application.
As such, I would like the flask commands to be nested under their own group.

### Example

I made a minimal example to demonstrate my problem - it's on GitHub here: https://github.com/ewels/flask-subcommand-issue

#### What works

In the minimal example, I set up a mini flask installation that runs with the `fsksc_server` command.
This is thanks to a setuptools `console_scripts` entry point hook in `setup.py`.

The command works perfectly, exactly as you would expect:

```
$ fsksc_server --help

Usage: fsksc_server [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

  Run the fsksc server flask app

Options:
  --version  Show the flask version
  --help     Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  routes  Show the routes for the app.
  run     Runs a development server.
  shell   Runs a shell in the app context.
```

```
$ fsksc_server run

 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

*(I haven't set up any routes, so visiting the URL throws a 404, but the server is running fine..)*

To get the flask commands in a click subcommand I have used flask `add_command` with the flask group.
This main command is `fsksc`. The flask subcommand should be `shell`.
The intention is to make `fsksc shell run` launch the development server.

The commands show up properly, so this part seems to work:

```
$ fsksc --help

Usage: fsksc [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  cmd1
  cmd2
  server  Run the fsksc server flask app
```

#### What doesn't work

When doing anything under the `server` subcommand, I get a warning message about a `NoAppException` exception:

```
$ fsksc server --help

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ewels/miniconda2/envs/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask-1.0.2-py2.7.egg/flask/cli.py", line 529, in list_commands
    rv.update(info.load_app().cli.list_commands(ctx))
  File "/Users/ewels/miniconda2/envs/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask-1.0.2-py2.7.egg/flask/cli.py", line 384, in load_app
    'Could not locate a Flask application. You did not provide '
NoAppException: Could not locate a Flask application. You did not provide the "FLASK_APP" environment variable, and a "wsgi.py" or "app.py" module was not found in the current directory.
Usage: fsksc server [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

  Run the fsksc server flask app

Options:
  --version  Show the flask version
  --help     Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  routes  Show the routes for the app.
  run     Runs a development server.
  shell   Runs a shell in the app context.
```

Trying to run the server gives a similar error:

```
$ fsksc server run

 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Usage: fsksc server run [OPTIONS]

Error: Could not locate a Flask application. You did not provide the "FLASK_APP" environment variable, and a "wsgi.py" or "app.py" module was not found in the current directory.
```

#### Crappy workaround

I can fix this by defining the `FLASK_APP` environment variable correctly.
Then `flask run` works as expected:

```
$ export FLASK_APP=/Users/ewels/GitHub/flask-subcommand-issue/fsksc/server/app.py:create_fsksc_app

$ fsksc server run

 * Serving Flask app "/Users/ewels/GitHub/flask-subcommand-issue/fsksc/server/app.py:create_fsksc_app"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

`flask run` also works.

*But* - I don't want to have to get my users to do this!
I also don't want to pollute my main command group with the flask subcommands
(in reality I have a lot more subcommands in the main group).

#### The question

What do I need to do to make this work as I intend, without having to define `FLASK_APP` and as a nested group in click?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so [Grey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55272314/713980) put me on the right track..

Unfortunately, because of how flask uses the `.flaskenv` files, paths have to either be absolute, or relative to the current working directory of the user. Neither of these approaches will work for other users installing the package.

However, when playing with this I found that doing a simple `os.environ['FLASK_APP']` works! It just has to be very early on in the script execution. Then the path can be set dynamically based on the location of the installed script, and I think everything seems to work:

```py
flaskenv_app_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'fsksc', 'server', 'app.py')
flaskenv_app_func = '{}:create_fsksc_app'.format(flaskenv_app_path)
os.environ['FLASK_APP'] = flaskenv_app_func
```

I've updated the minimal example code with this here: https://github.com/ewels/flask-subcommand-issue

Thank you for your help [Grey Li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5511849/grey-li)!

Answer (score 2):

Create a file named `.flaskenv` under the root of your project, put this content into it:

```py
FLASK_APP=fsksc.server.app:create_fsksc_app
```

then install python-dotenv:

```
$ pip install python-dotenv
```

Now the env var should be set automatically when you excute your run command.

Comment: Amazing, thank you! Note that I had to additionally specify a `flask.cli.load_dotenv()` command to get this working, but this had the added benefit that I could tidy the new `.flaskenv` file away in the subdirectory with the flask code. I also used a relative path for `FLASK_APP` so that it will work for all users.

A little annoyed with myself that I didn't figure this out myself - I had seen the [flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/cli/#environment-variables-from-dotenv) about `python-dotenv`, but hadn't put 2+2 together to realise that this would solve my problem. Thank you!

Comment: I updated the minimal solution on GitHub to help future readers: https://github.com/ewels/flask-subcommand-issue

Comment: Damn, I spoke too soon. The relative path doesn't work when you launch from other working directories. Any ideas how to make `FLASK_APP` work for any user?

Comment: You are welcome! Maybe you can just pass module import path, check the updated answer.

Comment: I don't think that this works sadly (I tried that). At least, not if you are not in the correct working directory. From the Flask docs: _Directories are scanned upwards from the directory you call `flask` from to locate the files. The current working directory will be set to the location of the file, with the assumption that that is the top level project directory._

Comment: Yes, with this setting, you have to excute the command from project root. Your solution looks good for your need, just up vote :)